# Android tv OS Device policy manager Activity not found

Tags: android, mdm, device-policy-manager

[image]I'm using Android policy manager and the following code works on `Android 5.0.x` mobile devices.

```
Intent deviceAdminIntent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                deviceAdminIntent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, cdmDeviceAdmin);
                deviceAdminIntent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                                           getResources().getString(R.string.device_admin_enable_alert));
                startActivityForResult(deviceAdminIntent, ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
```

However, when I deploying the same on Android TV image with the same `OS` version, it throws the following exception.What could be the issue? Where can I find the source[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqSVa.png) for `Android TV` images?

```
E/AgentApplication: UncaughtExceptionHandler got an exception
                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxx}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN (has extras) }
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN (has extras) }
                        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1798)
                        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqSVa.png). https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.java

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Android TV image"? Are you referring to an official Android SDK emulator, or something else?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response, I have attached a screenshot of what I'm refering to. 
To be more clear, I'm porting a MDM related app to work with Android TVs.

Comment: Well, the emulator doesn't have that particular activity exposed in Settings. If you navigate the Settings app directly, does it have anything for device management?

Comment: Interesting.. no It doesnt have the device admin area under security that you would find in regular devices. This is normally available in Android emulator for mobile devices. Is the Activity available in OS versions available in real hardware? I'm wondring why it is removed in the emulator images and I can't find any release tags or branches in Android source relevant to these particular images. Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: "This is normally available in Android emulator for mobile devices" -- agreed. I haven't used an official Android TV device in a while, and I don't think that I have a working one here in the lab. It is possible that Android TV does not offer device administration in general. "I can't find any release tags or branches in Android source relevant to these particular images" -- I have not tried looking for Android TV-specific material in the source code, sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I will test it on a real device and update my finding here.

Comment: Not all devices support device administration. If they do, they must set the "android.software.device_admin" feature. See section 3.9 in the CDD http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf .